# Vocabulary related to bid rigging

Tags: slang, business-japanese

In a bid rigging (談合入札) how do you call the suppliers:

- the one to win the contract
- others who are intended just to take part and to lose (I recall some expression with 馬)

As we are talking about illegal activity, I expect these expressions to be slangy.

Comment: found 対抗馬{たいこうば} for a "rival candidate", but I think there was more specific expression for a "horse that will definitely lose"

Comment: Right, it is not 「対抗馬」 as there is no competition among the "horses" to begin with in 談合.  Hint: There is a kana in the middle of the correct word.  And for your first question, the answer is a 2-or-4-kanji word containing 「命」.  Not sure why the experts have not posted an answer to this excellent question.  (Unfortunately, I am no longer answering questions here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be 本命 (the one to win) and 当{あ}て馬{うま} (the one to lose). I didn't find it out until I read the comment.

Comment: Thank you. 当て馬 is definitely the word I heard at work ("we were used as stalking horse").